# FXM showing 0 visits

Tags: fxm

We have added an external website to FXM (and the allowed domain to config).  When we go to the external website we can see the beacon is fired with 200 status, and the subsequent request receives a 200 status with response:

```
{"ContactId":"1ec8e91a0a5048fea3d84f3f638ef18b|True","SessionId":"tmpdxoun3f5mwhgyal1yqoxz","ContactExpires":"2021-07-14T13:35:44.7423139","SessionPath":"/","ElementMatches":[],"Id":null,"Url":null}
```

But still on the FXM page its showing 0 visits:
[image]

We have defined this rule - in case it's required for the visit to count.

[image]

It has also been over 24 hours so I think some data should be appearing by now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out whilst Sitecore 9.1 supports WAF configuration, it has a limitation where FXM tracking requests are blocked.  Appears to be due to the page URL not being encrypted and it triggering Owasp security rules.

It has been logged with Sitecore as a future feature request.